# MSBuild 15 The "TypeScript.Tasks.FindConfigFiles task" could not be loaded

Tags: c#, msbuild, asp.net-core

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 (release) and I'm trying to build a new ASP.Net MVC Core project programmatically using Microsoft.Build version 15 (from NuGet).

I'm getting this error message:

> ERROR C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets(164,5):
>   The "TypeScript.Tasks.FindConfigFiles" task could not be loaded from
>   the assembly C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\TypeScript\TypeScript.tasks.dll.
>   Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Framework,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   Confirm that the  declaration is correct, that the assembly
>   and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a
>   public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.
>             Skipping target "GenerateBuildDependencyFile" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
>       The thread 0x430c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>             : ERROR C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\build\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(129,5):
>   The "GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles" task failed unexpectedly.
>       System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Boolean NuGet.Frameworks.NuGetFramework.op_Equality(NuGet.Frameworks.NuGetFramework,
>   NuGet.Frameworks.NuGetFramework)'.
>          at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.LockFileExtensions.CreateProjectContext(LockFile
>   lockFile, NuGetFramework framework, String runtime, String
>   platformLibraryName)
>          at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles.ExecuteCore()
>          at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.TaskBase.Execute()
>          at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
>          at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__26.MoveNext()

So, Typescript.Tasks.dll could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'?

And error messages related to System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Boolean NuGet.Frameworks.NuGetFramework.

I have added these NuGet packages:

```
Microsoft.Build version 15.1.0.0
Microsoft.Build.Framework, version 15.1.0.0
Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core, version 15.1.0.0
Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core, version 15.1.0.0

Microsoft.CodeAnalysis (and all associated packages), version 2.0.0.0
```

I'm loading the ASP.Net MVC Core project successfully with

```
workspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create(new Dictionary<string, string> 
{  { "Configuration", "Debug" } });
```

Then later I'm trying to build the project with

```
Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection pc = new Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection();
pc.DefaultToolsVersion = "15.0";
Dictionary<string, string> globalProperties = new Dictionary<string, string>();
globalProperties.Add("Configuration", "Debug");
globalProperties.Add("Platform", "Any CPU");

var targetsToBuild = new[] { "Build" };
BuildRequestData buildRequest = new BuildRequestData(projectFullPath, globalProperties, "15.0", targetsToBuild, null);
```

Does anybody know what the problem is?

Comment: Anybody? I'm still banging my head in the wall. VS 2017 is compiling the same project just fine, but it's impossible to do it programmatically with Microsoft.Build from NuGet.